# Scheduling SQL Server Reporting Services reports (SSRS)

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, reporting

I recognize that SSRS has subscription/scheduling capability within the product that relies on  the SQL Server - SQL Agent for execution.

This out of the box method is not very robust however to enterprise wide deployment.

Are there alternatives to relying on SSRS-Scheduling (OOB) that others have used in it's place?

I have seen this product online [SQL-RD](http://www.christiansteven.com/sql-rd-video/) which seems like a viable alternative.  Are there other ways of achieving similar functionality without hand-coding?  What have other corporations done?

Comment: Have you considered using a [data-driven subscription](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159150.aspx)?  If so, in what ways are the functionalities provided through data-driven subscriptions insufficient for your requirements?

Comment: This issue is we have hundreds of different reports and thousands of people that can be recipients of them on.  I am looking for a product/tool that can allow the scheduled run of these reports AND also the product that will allow individuals to sign up/discontinue the reports.  The idea of having thousands of sql agent jobs within SQL Server not easily identifiable is not very nice, hence the reason for looking for another solution.

Comment: Currently we are using sql server 2008 (not 2012) as fyi

Comment: I was forced to use a "service agent" type approach to deal with the granularity of requirements for my project. The ssrs api offers more control over what you get out of the box, however, this requires extra projects interfacing with ssrs that you stated you do not want to produce. I would look at http://www.telerik.com/products/reporting.aspx they have wrapped the api and provide more than you get with ssrs.